# NGINX + webapp2 + Python problems

Tags: python, web-services, nginx, webapp2

I have been researching long but I cannot see how `webapp2` works outside `Google App Engine` ("GAE") ( in-combination with `NGINX` ). I really love `webapp2` and even though I can run it with `python script.py` how do we pass the python to `webapp2` and the rest to `NGINX`?

TL;DR - How do you get `NGINX` to work as close as possible to the `GAE` architecture? I find `GAE` very pleasant but it doesn't fit my needs in this case. Too many limitations.

Comment: Did you find the solution ?